# Forms in MS Access that reference the same data will not refresh until the other form is closed or loses focus

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am hoping some VBA/Access guru might just know how to address this because it seems that I am missing something fundamental, yet relatively simple for someone in the know.

I have three separate forms, all of which have separate subforms. On each of the subforms, there is a common piece of data (i.e. points to the same table/field in the database)

I want that if a user updates that common field on any of the three subforms, the other subforms should show that updated value without the user needing to manually refresh.

A note when I click "Refresh":
Even *if* the user hits the  refresh button, the changes take affect IFF the subform on which the change was made has lost the focus-- And no, the field losing the focus is not enough, the subform must lose the focus. Otherwise, clicking the refresh button doesn't work

I have some "AfterUpdate" code on each of the fields in the subforms that calls .Requery on the other two subforms. The requery syntax is correct. No errors or anything (Assuming the other two forms are open).

I am more than happy to include code if necessary, but literally, the only thing I am doing is calling requery on the other subforms

```
Forms("OtherformName1")!subformName1.Form.Requery 
Forms("OtherformName2")!subformName2.Form.Requery
```

I have also attempted to run this code using .Refresh (didn't work), and I have tried putting in the "LostFocus" event
Nothing seems to work. Does anyone have any idea what this might be?
It has to be simple because this feels like really basic functionality

Comment: It is not enough to update the field, it is the record that must be updated before calling a refresh of the other subforms.

Comment: Record entry/edit must be committed to table before data is available elsewhere. Why does this matter? Are all 3 main forms viewed at the same time? This sounds like an unusual situation. Are these forms identical in structure bound to 3 tables with identical structure?

Comment: Thank you for the information. I was under the perception that once a change was made in a field, "Access magic" committed it to the database for you. I guess the circumstances of that commit are a little more fuzzy than I thought.
And no, these forms are not identical in structure. The queries that back the forms all have one piece of data that might be needed in different contexts, which is why it is on three forms